# Problems with updating a texture

Tags: c++, c, opengl, textures

I have a function that generates the obj texture and another one that displays it. In order not to leak memory, I tried to call only one time the first function and than, use `glTexSubImage2D` in the second one, the problem is that this function is not working for me. When I start the program, the texture isn't being updating.

Here is the generating texture function:

```
    GLuint importText(const std::string &text,int font_size,int red,int green,int blue, texto_data *texto){
    SDL_Color font_color = {blue,green,red};
    TTF_Font* font=TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf",font_size);
    SDL_Surface *image = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font,text.c_str(),font_color);
    SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha(image);

    glGenTextures(1,&texto->texture);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texto->texture);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER,GL_LINEAR);

    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T,GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE);

    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,GL_RGBA,image->w,image->h,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image->pixels);

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);

    TTF_CloseFont(font);

    return texto->texture;
}
```

And here is the display function:

```
    int carrega_texto(texto_data *texto) {   

    SDL_Color font_color = {texto->b,texto->g,texto->r};
    TTF_Font* font = TTF_OpenFont("arial.ttf",texto->tamanho);
    SDL_Surface *image = TTF_RenderText_Blended(font,texto->string,font_color);
    SDL_DisplayFormatAlpha(image);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texto->texture);

    glTexSubImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0,0,image->w,image->h,0,GL_RGBA,GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE,image->pixels);

    SDL_FreeSurface(image);

    TTF_CloseFont(font);

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texto->texture);
    glColor4ub(255, 255, 255, 255);

    glBegin(GL_QUADS);
    glTexCoord2d(0,0);  glVertex2f(texto->area.a.x, texto->area.a.y);
    glTexCoord2d(1,0);  glVertex2f(texto->area.b.x, texto->area.b.y);
    glTexCoord2d(1,1);  glVertex2f(texto->area.c.x, texto->area.c.y);
    glTexCoord2d(0,1);  glVertex2f(texto->area.d.x, texto->area.d.y);
    glEnd();

}
```

Nt: I tried to just always call the generating texture and keeping deleting with `glDeleteTextures`, in order not to use `glTexSubImage2D`. The problem is that the `glGenTexture` always increases the variable *texto->texture* and than it overflow.

Comment: You NEED to be checking your opengl calls for errors.   Check after every single call.  https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Error  opengl is VERY particular about how it works and errors often don't materialize in ways you would expect

Comment: @Rabbid76 Because I need to update it frequently. I need to generate numbers as textures that will be updated at every single loop interaction, and I can't predict what numbers will be.

Comment: You can reuse the texture object and you don't need to delete a object and generate a new one. It would be sufficient to specify a new image by `glTexImage2D`. Do the textures have the same size? `glTexSubImage2D` can't change the size of the image, it can only update the content of a region of an existing image.

Comment: @Rabbid76 But won't glTexImage2D consume memory? Like, if I always update it? Maybe I'm mistaking, how would I reuse it? Yes, they have same size

Comment: @VictorF.Castor No, the named texture object is kept, but the data store is relocated and initialized. It cost a lot more time the `glTexSubImage2D` because of the complete relocation of the data store of the texture object.

Comment: @xaxxon Ok, thanks for the tip. It's my first time using OpenGL/SDL

Comment: Once you get the simplest possible program to show up on your screen, make VERY small steps so that when you do something wrong you know immediately.   So many errors show up as "black screen" that if you changed 5 different things, it's virtually impossible to know which caused it.   So take one baby step, run the program and make sure it still shows up.   one more baby step - check again, etc.   opengl is *hard* because the API is VERY particular and the debugging options are extremely limited compared to "normal" programming.

Comment: @Rabbid76 So, I just need to replace glTexSubImage2D to glTexImage2D?

Comment: @xaxxon alright, I'll confer the site you gave me